# Lost remaining record after validation error comes in MVC

Tags: c#, html, validation, asp.net-mvc-4, model

I have one MVC project,containing user registration form which have 25-30 fields to fill. After filling form if user forgot to fill mandatory field then it will shows validation error. But remaining all fields loss their data.
I mentioned in controller like

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            ModelToDBclass obj = new ModelToDBclass();
            objModel.Id = Convert.ToInt32(obj.GetMaxPaperId());
            objModel.countryNameDB = obj.GetcountryName();
            return View(objModel);
        }
```

and finally it returns the blank view. but at runtime when it comes to

*return View(objModel);* , the model shows the data with every field, but when it comes to view it unable to show record in text boxes and dropdown. I used textbox like,

```
<div class="col-sm-2"><input type="text"  class="form-control" name="ConsumerFName" id="txtConsumerFirstName" placeholder="First Name" />
                                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ConsumerFName)</div>
```

so, please help me how can i display filled record after validation error

Comment: Can you use `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.ConsumerFName, new { @placeholder = "First Name", @class = "form-control" })`? In that case values will be persisted.

Comment: Do not manually generate your html. Use the strongly typed html helpers (e.g. `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ConsumerFName)` which takes care of this and other features such as client side validation

Comment: you are saying replace all textbox and write above line .am i right...??

Comment: yes, and ofcourse with right model properties.

Comment: ok @StephenMuecke , but how can i apply unique css for a specific control..?

Comment: `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ConsumerFName, new { @class = "yourClass" })`

Comment: ok thanks bot of you,  i am trying  your suggestion...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should always use `Html Helper`

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" }, placeholder = "First Name", autofocus = "autofocus" })
```

Then only when the `Model state` is not valid, it will show the returned object values at the respective fields. Don't normal html tags.
Hope this helps